# VB.net - Using an Editor Template on a collection = null model in controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

**Here is my class**

```
Public Class ManageStudents
    Public Students As New List(Of ManageStudentLine)
End Class
```

**I have a view that calls my editortemplate**

```
@ModelType ViewModel.ManageStudents

@Html.EditorFor(Model.Students)
```

**Here is my editor template**

```
@ModelType ViewModel.ManageStudentLine

@Using Html.BeginForm()
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.StudentNumber)
    <Button type="submit"/>
end using
```

So what I am trying to do is to have the `EditorFor()` iterate over the collection of `ManageStudentLines` and produce a separate form for each `ManageStudentLine`.  The problem arises when the form is submitted, the model comes back as empty.

I have tried using a `foreach` in the main view to iterate over the collection and just call the `EditorFor()` on the single object, but that doesn't work.

I have also tried moving the form tag outside of the editor template and that doesn't work.

I initially moved everything to a `EditorTemplate` because I was having issues with client side data validations not working.  The `EditorTemplate` has fixed that, but my model is empty.

Surely I'm not the first person to want to iterated over a collection and have each object be a separate form with working validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EditorFor()` method generates your form controls correctly for a collection with indexers s the the html you generating is

```
<input type="text" name="Students[0].StudentNumber" ... />
<input type="text" name="Students[1].StudentNumber" ... />
```

which means you need to post back the whole collection (in a single form) to a method which has a parameter `List(Of ManageStudentLine) model`.

Having multiple forms for a collection makes no sense since you can only submit one form at a time, and means your could never return the view if there were any validation errors.

Change your view to

```
@ModelType ViewModel.ManageStudents

@Using Html.BeginForm()
    @Html.EditorFor(Model.Students)
    <button type="submit"/>
end using
```

and the `EditorTemplate` to

```
@ModelType ViewModel.ManageStudentLine
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.StudentNumber)
```

which will allow you to edit all items in the collection and correctly post back the collection.

Note if you did want to generate one form for each item you cannot use the `HtmlHelper` methods and you would need to manually generate the html as

```
<input type="text" name="StudentNumber" ... />
```

and you would lose all the benefits of model binding, validation etc.